# Output YOLOv8 Terminal output to Tkinter ScrolledText box

Tags: python, tkinter, yolo, yolov8

so I am currently making a GUI for training a yolo model using tkinter and I can't seem to get the terminal output to go into my GUI. By that, I mean YOLO's standard terminal output such as

```
Transferred 355/355 items from pretrained weights
train: Scanning C:\---\train\labels.cache... 1977 images, 81 
val: Scanning C:\---\valid\labels.cache... 145 images, 8 back
Plotting labels to runs\detect\train17\labels.jpg... 
optimizer: AdamW(lr=0.002, momentum=0.9) with parameter groups 57 weight(decay=0.0), 64 weight(decay=0.0005), 63 bias(decay=0.0)
Image sizes 960 train, 960 val
Using 0 dataloader workers
Logging results to runs\detect\train17
Starting training for 10 epochs...
Closing dataloader mosaic

      Epoch    GPU_mem   box_loss   cls_loss   dfl_loss  Instances       Size
  0%|          | 0/124 [00:02<?, ?it/s]
```

I am using a scrolledtext box currently for where I want the output to go as such:

```
output_text = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(left_frame, wrap=tk.WORD)
output_text.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="nsew")
```

and have tried using sys to redirect as well as threading and output capturing but it still always outputs the yolo dialogue into the VS code dialogue.
If I print something in the code however, that shows in my GUI. So it seems its redirecting everything but the YOLO outputs (which is info like epoch training progression etc.)
Has anyone experienced working with this before and how could I implement a way to output the YOLO dialogue into my tkinter GUI.
Thanks
edit:
this is the code that runs YOLO currently (called from clicking a train model button), this is a random attempt with sys.stdout that does not work:

```
def modelTrain(): #function to train model
    if trainModel == 'none' or trainModel == '': #conditions to check user has selected everything required for training
        tk.messagebox.showwarning("No model set", "You must set a model for training on (PyTorch .pt file)")
        return #if conditions not met we show a warning and exit function
    if trainDataset == 'none' or trainDataset == '':
        tk.messagebox.showwarning("No dataset set", "You must set a dataset for training (YOLO .yaml file)")
        return
    if epochs == 0:
        tk.messagebox.showwarning("Number of epochs not set", "You must set the amount of epochs to train for")
        return
    if imgsize == 0:
        tk.messagebox.showwarning("Input image size not set", "You must set the size of the images as exported for training")
        return
    
    model = YOLO(trainModel) #setting model to one selected by user
    dataset = trainDataset #setting dataset to one selected by user

    def train_in_thread(): #training model in seperate thread to avoid gui freezing from model training using up sys resources 
        model.train(data=dataset, epochs=epochs, pretrained=True, imgsz=imgsize)#initializing model training with other vars set by user
        model.val()

        output_text.insert(tk.END, "Training completed.\n")
        output_text.see(tk.END)  # Scroll to the end

    # Create a separate thread to run the training function
    train_thread = threading.Thread(target=train_in_thread)
    train_thread.start()
```

Comment: Please show the code that calls yolo.

Comment: @BryanOakley I have edited to show

Comment: Please fix the indentation.

Comment: @toyotaSupra its normal in my code, must have just gone weird into stack overflow. let me re-copy it